# Using web_accessible_resources to expose a text file only to the Chrome extension itself

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use a text file which contains useful data for this Chrome extension I'm developing. However, I don't want webpages to be able to see this file.

Therefore, I tried to list this file as a `web accessible resource` which would only be available for the extension ID of the extension itself, as shown below.

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": [
            "data/file.txt"
        ],
        "extension_ids": [
            "the-id-of-my-extension"
        ]
    }
]
```

However, when I try `chrome.runtime.getURL("data/file.txt")`, I get the following error:
`Denying load of ... Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.`

I couldn't find anything to help with this problem, as all solutions online use `matches` and `<all_urls>` which is not something I can do as I'd like to keep the file unexposed to webpages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your files are not exposed to the internet when you use `matches`.

Comment: From developer.chrome.com : `Web-accessible resources are files inside an extension that can be accessed by web pages or other extensions.`. Does this not mean what I think it means ?

Comment: Not at all. There's no way "data/file.txt" that exists on your computer is exposed to the internet.

Comment: Even when you deploy the extension ? The file would then be part of the extension so I guess it would no longer just be on your computer

Comment: If you want to limit the access to your own content script there's no solution until https://crbug.com/1383176 is fixed and you'll be able to do it via `use_dynamic_url`. 

P.S. You can't use `extension_ids` here because it grants access to an *extension process* and not to the *web page process* where all content scripts run. Note that if you read the file inside your own extension process (e.g. the action popup or the background service worker script) there's no need for web_accessible_resources, these contexts can always do it via `fetch('/path/file.txt')`.